# A ruby library that will create a new repository on github programmatically

Tags: git, github

I am looking for a ruby library which will allow me to create a new project on github without first creating the project on github. Is that even possible? I came across this one http://timeless.judofyr.net/gash but not sure how to push the project on github.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the "hub" project: https://github.com/defunkt/hub